# Split string at python

Tags: python, string, split

`n = int(input())
for _ in range(n):
    string = input()
    print(string[0::2], string[1::2])`

what the mean of string[0::2], is something like str_split at PHP or different

Comment: It's Python slicing notation; you can find more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295)

Comment: That's a slice. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L22zs3v6Rtg

Comment: in simple term  for any iterable it is start index, end index, and  iincrement step

Comment: but, why in the code has a 4 property inside string[1::2], if must be 3 start,end, increment.  So my code still run and nothing wrong happen.